# Function Types tutorial from Apple

Tags: swift

So, I followed this [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) from Apple.

But it would not allow me to declare a var mathFunction as in the tutorial.

```
func addTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int
{
    return a + b
}

func multiplyTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int
{
    return a * b
}

typealias MathFunctionType = (Int, Int) -> Int
```

When I started typing add... or mult... it expected an input paramenter of ViewController.  ( see image 1,2)

```
var mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int = addTwoInts(ViewController)

var mathFunction2: MathFunctionType = multiplyTwoInts(ViewController)
```

These two line will generate an error (see image 3)

```
var mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int = addTwoInts
var mathFunction2: MathFunctionType = multiplyTwoInts
```

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why the compile time error?

Since your functions are within a class, they are owned by *instances* of that class. Hence, attempting to directly initialize your closures to references to these instance function *prior to an instance of the class itself being initialized*, is not possible.

Instead, you have two methods to seemingly resolve this:

- Make the methods class (static) methods, owned by the class *type* rather than instances of it.
- Or, delay initialization of your closures until all stored properties of the class itself has been initialized (*including the closures*, e.g. in some initializer), whereafter you can assign references to the functions to the closures. As we shall see the next section, this *does* seemingly resolve the compile time errors, but instead, if we do not take care, introduces a strong reference cycle.

E.g.:

```
class Foo {

    typealias MathFunctionType = (Int, Int) -> Int

    /* refer to class function (no instance needed) */
    static func addTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
        return a + b
    }
    var mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int = Foo.addTwoInts

    /* delayed initialization to instance function reference */
    func multiplyTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
        return a * b
    }
    let someIntInNeedOfInitialization: Int
    var mathFunction2: MathFunctionType? = nil

    init() {

        // initialize class properties
        someIntInNeedOfInitialization = 42

        // allowing use of 'self' to refer to own-instance function
        // ... warning, strong reference cycle!
        mathFunction2 = self.multiplyTwoInts
    }
}
```

Or, if you'd like to avoid your closures being optionals, you can assign dummy closures to them -> hence fully initializing the class instance, whereafter you can access the instances methods using prefix `.self`. E.g.:

```
class Foo {

    typealias MathFunctionType = (Int, Int) -> Int

    /* delayed initialization to instance function reference */
    func multiplyTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
        return a * b
    }
    let someIntInNeedOfInitialization: Int
    var mathFunction2: MathFunctionType

    init() {

        // initialize class properties
        someIntInNeedOfInitialization = 42
        mathFunction2 = { _, _ in return 0 } // dummy initialization

        // allowing use of 'self' to refer to own-instance function
        // ... warning, strong reference cycle!
        mathFunction2 = self.multiplyTwoInts
    }
}
```

### Resolved? Be aware of strong reference cycles!

From the above we seemingly solved your issues, but there is a danger initializing a closure with a reference to `self`, as we run the risk of creating [strong reference cycles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID56), in which case a class instance is not de-initilized when we expect it to be.

- Since the closure itself is a reference type, the class instance keeps a strong reference to the closure, hence keeping it "alive" via ARC.
- If we, in addition, let the closure itself own a strong reference to the class instance (owning it), we've created a strong reference cycle.

As we can see in the following example, letting closures *owned by a class refer to instance methods of the same class* creates just such a strong reference cycle:

```
class Foo {

    typealias MathFunctionType = (Int, Int) -> Int

    /* delayed initialization to instance function reference */
    func multiplyTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
        return a * b
    }

    // Foo.self -> [strong ref.] -> mathFunction2 (reference type)
    var mathFunction2: MathFunctionType = { _, _ in return 0 }

    init() {

        // mathFunction2 -> [strong ref.] -> Foo.self (reference type)
        mathFunction2 = self.multiplyTwoInts
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinitialized")
    }
}

func foo() {
    let _ = Foo()
}

foo() // nothing prints, wups!
```

**Solution #1: Only add references from closure to `class` methods and not same-instance-as-closure-methods**

The above is naturally not an issue if we refer to class (static) functions, as these does not yield a strong reference from your closure to to class instance which owns the closure

```
class Foo {

    /* refer to class function (no instance needed) */
    static func addTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
        return a + b
    }
    var mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int = Foo.addTwoInts

    deinit {
        print("deinitialized")
    }
}

func foo() {
    let _ = Foo()
}

foo() // "deinitialized", ok!
```

**Solution #2: Use capture lists to avoid strong reference to `self`**

As an alternative, we can let the closure explicitly call the class method with its own arguments, but while using a [*capture list*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) to specify that the reference to `self` (as in reference to the class instance) from within the closure is `unowned`, in so avoiding a strong reference cycle:

```
class Foo {

    typealias MathFunctionType = (Int, Int) -> Int

    /* delayed initialization to instance function reference */
    func multiplyTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
        return a * b
    }

    // Foo.self -> [strong ref.] -> mathFunction2 (reference type)
    var mathFunction2: MathFunctionType = { _, _ in return 0 }

    init() {

        // mathFunction2 -> [unowned ref.] -> Foo.self (reference type)
        mathFunction2 = { [unowned self] (a, b) -> Int in return self.multiplyTwoInts(a, b) }
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinitialized")
    }
}

func foo() {
    let _ = Foo()
}

foo() // "deinitialized", OK!
```

Comment: I tried out both class method and public method.  For me at least for now, it seemed to be logical and much simpler to maintain. Great explaination.  Wish Apple included this part for this tutorial.

Comment: @user523234 Happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

That tutorial assumes the functions you're defining are *free functions* (aka top-level functions); that is, not methods within a class or other type.

So, if you have the following code outside of a class (as top-level code, or in a playground), it'll work fine:

```
func addTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int { /*...*/ }
var mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int = addTwoInts
```

If a class gets involved, there are two issues:

1. Your method (function) is a member of the class, and needs to be referenced as such
2. There are two valid ways to reference your method:

   - One is a curried function (a function that returns another function): if your class is called `Foo`, the global name `addTwoInts` is a function of type `(Foo) -> (Int, Int) -> Int`. That is, it's a function that takes an instance of `Foo` and returns another function of type `(Int, Int) -> Int`.
   - The name `addTwoInts` that's a member of a `Foo` instance has type `(Int, Int) -> Int`.

In other words, your code will also work fine if *all* of it is within a class:

```
class Foo {
    func addTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int { /*...*/ }
    func foo() {
        var mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int = addTwoInts
        //...
    }
}
```

Here, the `addTwoInts` reference inside the `foo()` function is implicitly referencing `self.addTwoInts` (which has the matching type), not the global `addTwoInts` (which is a curried function).

However, if you define your functions as members of a type, and reference them from elsewhere, you need to either explicitly reference them as members, or pass an instance of that type to the curried function to get the function you want.

```
class Foo {
    func addTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int { /*...*/ }
}
let bar = Foo()

// the following lines each do the same thing:
let addA: MathFunctionType = bar.addTwoInts
let addB: MathFunctionType = addTwoInts(bar)
```

If your variables `mathFunction` and `mathFunction2` are properties of the same class, you're in the same situation — the initialization expressions for these properties run before an instance of your class exists, so they can't reference that instance. You can define them without values and initialize them with values, though:

```
class Foo {
    func addTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int { /*...*/ }

    var mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int

    init() {
        super.init() 
        // super.init() is not needed in this example,
        // but if you have it, the below must come after it, not before 
        mathFunction = addTwoInts // implicitly self.addTwoInts
    }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation.

Comment: Nice answer (currying explanation )! Just two notes on the last code example block: _(1):_ `mathFunction` cannot be initialized with `addTwoInts` (implicitly `self.addTwoInts`) since this refers to `self` prior to `self` being fully initialized; i.e., prior to property `mathFunction` being initialized (_"catch-22"_). We can naturally circumvent this by first initializing `mathFunction` to a dummy (say `{ _, _ in return 0 }`), and thereafter mutate it to a reference to `self.addTwoInts`. Which leads to _(2):_ this however, creates a strong reference cycle between `self` and `mathFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that these two functions are defined inside the class ViewController.

```
func addTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int
{
    return a + b
}

func multiplyTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int
{
    return a * b
}
```

You are calling the instance of functions without creating one. One way is to extract these methods out of the ViewController. Or just use that code in a playground without creating any class.